# Constant `array of cardinal` produces error 'Constant expression violates subrange bounds"

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-xe4

Why the following code:

```
const
  ANSICOLORS: array of cardinal = [
    $000000,//0
    $800000,//1, compilation error starts with this value
    $008000,//2
    $808000,//3
    $000080,//4
    $800080,//5
    $008080,//6
    $D0D0D0,//7
    $3F3F3F,//8
    $FF0000,//9
    $00FF00,//A
    $FFFF00,//B
    $0000FF,//C
    $FF00FF,//D
    $00FFFF,//E
    $FFFFFF];//F
```

Would produce the following compilation error under Delphi XE4 (both win32 and win64):

> [dcc32 Error] Debug.pas(66): E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds

Isn't value `$800000` within the range of `Cardinal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a memory perspective, `$800000` indeed is within the range of `Cardinal`.

I thought it the `Cardinal($800000)` typecast would fix it, but it doesn't.

Delphi XE7 and up actually compile your code correctly.

This also fails up until Delphi XE6 with the same error:

```
const
  CardinalArray: array of Cardinal = [257];
```

I think the reason is that the Delphi compiler sees `[257]` as a `set`, despite the left side indicating it is supposed to be an `array`.

This fails in XE4, but compile fine in XE7 and up:

```
program Cardinals;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

const
  CardinalArray: array of Cardinal = [257]; // fails until Delphi XE4 with "E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds"

const
  ANSICOLORS: array of Cardinal = [
    $000000,//0
    $800000,//1, compilation error starts with this value
    $008000,//2
    $808000,//3
    $000080,//4
    $800080,//5
    $008080,//6
    $D0D0D0,//7
    $3F3F3F,//8
    $FF0000,//9
    $00FF00,//A
    $FFFF00,//B
    $0000FF,//C
    $FF00FF,//D
    $00FFFF,//E
    $FFFFFF];//F

var
  AnsiColor: Cardinal;

begin
  try
    for AnsiColor in AnsiColors do
      Writeln(Format('$%6.6x', [AnsiColor]));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Output:

```
$000000
$800000
$008000
$808000
$000080
$800080
$008080
$D0D0D0
$3F3F3F
$FF0000
$00FF00
$FFFF00
$0000FF
$FF00FF
$00FFFF
$FFFFFF
```

If you can live with a non-dynamic array, then the below example works in Delphi XE4 (I tested it as far back as Delphi 2007, for XE and earlier, you have to replace `System.SysUtils` with `SysUtils`)).

Note the switches:

- from `array of Cardinal` to `array[0..15] of Cardinal`
- from `[` and `]` to `(` and `)`

```
program Cardinals;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

//{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

const
  ANSICOLORS: array[0..15] of Cardinal = (
    $000000,//0
    $800000,//1, compilation error starts with this value
    $008000,//2
    $808000,//3
    $000080,//4
    $800080,//5
    $008080,//6
    $D0D0D0,//7
    $3F3F3F,//8
    $FF0000,//9
    $00FF00,//A
    $FFFF00,//B
    $0000FF,//C
    $FF00FF,//D
    $00FFFF,//E
    $FFFFFF);//F

var
  AnsiColor: Cardinal;

begin
  try
    for AnsiColor in AnsiColors do
      Writeln(Format('$%6.6x', [AnsiColor]));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: I ran it from the commandline compilers I still had which indicated 14.0 and 15.0, so I assumed XE4 and XE5. Thanks for verifying it. Fixed the answer.

Comment: The XE5 compiler version is 26.0, but the BDS version is 12.0. This means that *\RAD Studio\14.0\bin contains XE6 and *\15.0\bin contains XE7.

Answer (score 8):

You are using a feature introduced in XE7.

Declaring a dynamic array constant.

[Dynamic arrays_Delphi xe7](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2014_september_dynamic_arrays_delphixe7.html) and

[String-Like_Operations_Supported_on_Dynamic_Arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE7#String-Like_Operations_Supported_on_Dynamic_Arrays)

---

In XE4, this is evaluated as a set, where the ordinality cannot exceed 255.

Hence the error `E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds`

Fix it by declaring:

```
const
  ANSICOLORS: array[0..15] of cardinal = (
    $000000,//0
    $800000,//1, 
    $008000,//2
    $808000,//3
    $000080,//4
    $800080,//5
    $008080,//6
    $D0D0D0,//7
    $3F3F3F,//8
    $FF0000,//9
    $00FF00,//A
    $FFFF00,//B
    $0000FF,//C
    $FF00FF,//D
    $00FFFF,//E
    $FFFFFF);//F
```